# Remote WMI Call for Disk Serial Number

Tags: vbscript, wmi

I'm a relatively inexperienced coder and I've been running into an issue with getting the physical disk serial number remotely via a VBScript.

Currently I'm using the default script in Scriptomatic V2, by the Scripting Guys.  I'm running it from a 2003 Server and trying to get info from Win2000 and WinXP SP2/SP3 systems.  I've seen from a couple tutorials that the WMI class recommended is Win32_PhysicalMedia.

Including the useful bits:

```
On Error Resume Next

Const wbemFlagReturnImmediately = &h10
Const wbemFlagForwardOnly = &h20

arrComputers = Array("STN_XP","STN_2000")
  For Each strComputer In arrComputers
    WScript.Echo
    WScript.Echo "=========================================="
    WScript.Echo "Computer: " & strComputer
    WScript.Echo "=========================================="

    Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & strComputer & "\root\CIMV2")
    Set colItems = objWMIService.ExecQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_PhysicalMedia", "WQL", _
                                      wbemFlagReturnImmediately + wbemFlagForwardOnly)

    For Each objItem In colItems
      '(Removed a couple from the code, just showing the useful ones)
      WScript.Echo "Model: " & objItem.Model
      WScript.Echo "Name: " & objItem.Name
      WScript.Echo "SerialNumber: " & objItem.SerialNumber
      WScript.Echo "Tag: " & objItem.Tag
      WScript.Echo
      Next
    Next
```

Now the output I get is below:  Note this is the exact output from running the script with all calls; no data is returned beyond the objItem.Tag value:

```
==========================================
Computer: STN_XP
==========================================
Capacity:
Caption:
CleanerMedia:
CreationClassName:
Description:
HotSwappable:
Manufacturer:
MediaDescription:
MediaType:
Model:
Name:
OtherIdentifyingInfo:
PartNumber:
PoweredOn:
Removable:
Replaceable:
SerialNumber:
SKU:
Status:
Tag: \\.\PHYSICALDRIVE0
Version:
WriteProtectOn:

==========================================
Computer: STN_2000
==========================================
```

All computers are connected to a domain, I'm logged in to the primary admin account.  Using some of the other WMI libraries, I get data, and on one specific computer so far I've received a serial number (and tag, but nothing else).  I've read up on this being an issue for Vista, where you are required to run in admin mode.  This shouldn't be an issue here, due to the OSes in use.  Anyone know what might be wrong?

As a follow-up question, does anyone know how to get the Serial Number from a 2000 station?

Thanks in advance for any help you can give me.

Comment: So, what's the question?

Comment: Question is how can I get the serial number for a hard drive remotely.

objItem.SerialNumber should work, but doesn't.  Is there something that needs to be done by me to access to it, or is there another way around that I can take?

Comment: Ah, sorry.  I just realized what you meant.  There is no data being returned.  The output that I see is exactly as shown, no data beyond the Tag: is being returned properly.  Edited the OP to clarify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Comment out the On Error Resume Next with a single quote, and post the error message that is likely being returned.

Comment: I receive an error almost immediatedly on the Win2000 station.  
    ==========================================  
    Computer: STN_11  
    ==========================================  
    C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\Desktop\Scriptomatic\temp_script.sm(16,
4) (null): 0x80041010

Comment: For the XP station, I receive a mismatch error for CDate (which wasn't shown on the original output for that reason). Removing all calls but for SerialNumber and tag gives:  

==========================================
Computer: STN_16
==========================================
SerialNumber:
Tag: \\.\PHYSICALDRIVE0

Comment: It seems on the 2000 machine you don't have the WMI provider installed. You can install it via Add Remove Programs -> Windows Components -> Management and Monitoring Tools -> WMI Windows Management Installer Provider.



For the second one, it seems it's working, however your hardware vendor is not populating this field. You could try using WMITools and manually browsing to see if it might be populated in some other property or object.

http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=24045

Comment: Thanks, I downloaded the WMITools, and it helped me check out a couple classes easier.

Been checking online regarding this as well.  It seems that the general concensus for this is that finding the serial number via WMI calls is buggy and tempermental.  Thanks for all the help/suggestions, but it looks like I'll just be doing this manually.